# swift : tableViewcell initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class which has a collectionview inside. In this class there's a varaible "nbElements" which contain the number of collectionview cells to display. I want to know how I can initialize the value of nbElements when I create a tableview cell with `dequeueReusableCell`?

Here is the code of the custom tableview cell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var nbElements = Int!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell")

    self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nbElements
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellWidth = (self.collectionView.frame.width / 2.0) - 1
    let size = CGSize.init(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    return size;
}
```

}

Here is the code when I create a tableview cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.nbElements = 4
    return cell
}
```

Regards.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? However you should declare `nbElements` as non-optional `var nbElements = 0`, your line doesn't compile.

Comment: @vadian In this example, I wanted to show 4 cells in the collectionView but it's not the case.

Comment: Where do you call `reloadData()` on the collection view?

Comment: How have you set the `UICollectionView` `delegate` and `dataSource`?

Comment: @Rikh The delegate and the datasource are set.

Comment: @vadian Where I call the reloadData?

Comment: That's my question. To display data in a table view or collection view you have to call `reloadData()` (unless you're using `NSFetchedResultsController`)

Comment: @vadian My question was where I use reloadData() ?

Comment: @Rikh I set the datasource and delegate via the Interface Builder.

Comment: Normally at the moment when the data source array has been populated.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger reload of collectionView whenever the `nbElements` is set.

```
var nbElements = Int! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```